# Unable to get cucumber working with Ruby 2.x under Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, cucumber

When I run cucumber, I get the following messages:

```
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows
Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'
From:
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/core_ext/disable_mini_and_test_unit_autorun.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:21:in `initialize'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `new'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `execute!'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
undefined method `_run_suite' for class `Test::Unit::Runner' (NameError)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:676:in `<class:Runner>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:261:in `<module:Unit>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:15:in `<module:Test>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/test/unit.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/core_ext/disable_mini_and_test_unit_autorun.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:21:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:40:in `execute!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

`bundle list` gives me:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Gems included by the bundle:
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.7.7)
  * cucumber (1.2.1)
  * diff-lcs (1.1.3)
  * gherkin (2.11.8)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * minitest (4.7.5)
  * multi_json (1.10.1)
  * rspec-expectations (2.11.2)
```

Based on a similar question on stack exchange, I have the following in `features\support\env.rb':

```
require 'minitest'
module MiniTestAssertions
  def self.extended(base)
    base.extend(MiniTest::Assertions)
    base.assertions = 0
  end

  attr_accessor :assertions
end
World(MiniTestAssertions)
```

What's my next step to getting cucumber working?

Edit:

I've tried running cucumber in a completely empty directory (expecting to get a warning that no features are defined), but get exactly the same message: the warning about minitest, then the error about `undefined method '_run_suite'`. Evertyhing I can find on the web about this either relates to Rails (which I'm not using) or says it's an old problem that has been fixed, so I'm completely stuck. :(

Comment: Are you trying to test with Minitest or with RSpec? (You can use Cucumber for either, but it's much more typical of RSpec, which typically doesn't need Minitest)

Comment: I'd prefer to use RSpec, but I don't seem to have been given the choice yet! (I'm just following the instructions in The Cucumber Book, which worked fine on a different machine with Ruby 1.9 instead of 2.x).

How do I persuade it to use RSpec?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't use ruby 1.9 for going through this exercise?

The latest version of the `The Cucumber Book` - version 3.0 - was released in Mar 2014 when ruby 1.9.3 was the most prevalently used ruby version.

The code for the book was tested with `ruby 1.9.3-p194` (as mentioned in `Appendix 2 - Installing Cucumber` section).

The authors/pragprog may come up with a new edition of the book, and at that time they will ensure the code in the book work with `ruby 2.2` or the then most commonly used version of ruby.

It is quite possible to figure out how to make these examples work for `ruby 2.0` or higher version, but that is a headache I would recommend you not concern yourself at this time. Given that you are just now starting to learn about cucumber, it would be best to follow the text in the book based on the version it recommends.

After getting familiar with cucumber, and other components of the ruby world, you will appreciate why I find "How do I persuade it to use RSpec?" to be very funny. :-)

Comment: I've actually been using Cucumber for almost a year, under Ruby 1.9.3. But I'm working with Ruby 2.x on a different computer, and went back to The Cucumber Book to refresh my memory on how to set up an initial Cucumber configuration. Yes, I know Cucumber and RSpec perform different roles, but the error I was getting specifically referred to minitest, which as I understand it performs a function closer to RSpec than Cucumber.

Answer (score -1):

As you know, the configuration of your development environment is a tedious and error-prone task. I prefer to work in a *nix-type environment, which you could achieve on your Windows box using, say, VirtualBox or some Docker-for-Windows arrangement.

If you can get such a Docker configuration for Windows up and running, then this may be your best bet to solve the issue quickly, since Docker is all about sharing/reusing pre-configured environments/deployments, which can be a real time-saver! There are already some fine Dockerfile configurations that should help you see which components to install. See: [this](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dewiring/spec_cucumber/) and [that](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dewiring/spec_base/dockerfile/).

BTW, if you prefer to use rspec over minitest (and who wouldn't?), you'll want to use some sample code that doesn't "require 'minitest'". If you only are interested to get the current example working, you might entertain the idea that is given by the error message to "require 'minitest/autorun'". I hope it helps you--good luck!

Comment: This needs to work under Windows. Changing OS (or running in a VM) is not an option. And yes, I tried `require 'minitest/autorun`.

Comment: Did you look into the Dockerfiles to get an idea of the correct set of components to install? How nice that I get downvoted here for providing a possible (given that you failed to mention the constraint) alternative while the one other answer basically suggests you don't do what you want to do at all.

Comment: As far as I can see, Docker is a virtual machine too, so it's no solution. My stated question said *under Windows*; using a different OS is no answer to that (but a tiresome response I get *whenever* I ask about problems with Ruby config). Neither answer actually answers my question, but the other one is something I /could/ do as a fallback if I can't get 2.x working; your answer isn't.

That wouldn't normally have merited a downvote, but StackOverflow was about to automatically allocate the bounty, and the first answer was more deserving and I wasn't sure how else to direct it the better way.

Comment: Wasn't particularly conscious of a bounty here.. Anyway, if you drill into the docker files it may be helpful to see which components to install even though these are admittedly geared to Unix. Sorry you feel this way about Unix, BTW.

Comment: Oh, I have nothing against Unix -- it's just that I don't get to choose what OS I use at work, so the constant echo of "don't do it in Windows" is unhelpful.

If I remember, I'll undo the downvote in a few days, because I don't actually want to damage your rep for trying to be helpful -- as I said, it was the only way I could see to manage the bounty (well, the other way would have been to mark something that wasn't the answer as being the answer).

Comment: So, it appears that maybe you have an environment configuration problem. Docker can help solve that and fast. I had heard about Microsoft embracing Docker and Docker clients for Windows. I see now that the noise Microsoft was making was about supporting Docker was with respect to their Azure cloud offering (didn't know they offered Linux boxes in their cloud until just now). Looks like you are correct that their Windows client simply fires up a VM, and that is pretty lame, IMO. Anyway, I meant well. Sorry you don't have a better option than Windows.